# Spartan 3E array indexing

Tags: arrays, indexing, vhdl, spartan

I've been studying Pedroni's Circuit Design and Simulation in VHDL from 2010. I have an Open3S500E development board and am using Xilinx ISE 14.7 (newer don't support Spartan 3).
I have been stuck on "Exercise 9.5: Function my_not" which requires to use a resolution table(?):

```
-----------------------------------------------
CONSTANT not_table: stdlogic_1d :=
-----------------------------------------------
-- U    X    0    1    Z    W    L    H    -
-----------------------------------------------
( 'U', 'X', '1', '0', 'X', 'X', '1', '0', 'X');
-----------------------------------------------
```

regardless of what I did I always received an Error `Unsupported type stdlogic_1d .` I tried different things but failed every time. Finally I decided to copy and build Example 9.6 which used a similar table:

```
 TYPE stdlogic_table IS ARRAY(STD_ULOGIC, STD_ULOGIC) OF STD_ULOGIC;
 CONSTANT and_table: stdlogic_table := (
 -----------------------------------------------
 --U     X    0    1    Z    W    L    H    -
 -----------------------------------------------
 ( 'U', 'U', '0', 'U', 'U', 'U', '0', 'U', 'U' ), --| U |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' ), --| X |
 ( '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ), --| 0 |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X' ), --| 1 |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' ), --| Z |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' ), --| W |
 ( '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ), --| L |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X' ), --| H |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' )); --| - |
 -----------------------------------------------   `
```

..and I got the same result. Finally, I came to conclusion that there must be something wrong with Spartan 3 and changed family to Spartan 6 which worked like a charm.

There are couple of questions on my mind here. Why does it work on Spartan 6 and on Spartan 3? Must be about indexing with STD_LOGIC, right? I thought this was language specific feature and not hardware related. Are STD_LOGIC values enumerated somewhere? If so, what difference does it make if I index with 'U' or 0?. I know it's kind of a specific question and in the end it doesn't matter since Spartan 3 is already ancient, but I would love to know the answer.

Disclaimer: I am a VHDL newbie and an amateur programmer.

```vhdl
---------Package:-----------------------------------------------------
 LIBRARY ieee;
 USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 PACKAGE PEX9_6 IS
 FUNCTION my_and (a, b: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) RETURN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
 END PACKAGE;
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 PACKAGE BODY PEX9_6 IS
 TYPE stdlogic_table IS ARRAY(STD_ULOGIC, STD_ULOGIC) OF STD_ULOGIC;
 CONSTANT and_table: stdlogic_table := (
 -----------------------------------------------
 --UX01ZWLH-
 -----------------------------------------------
 ( 'U', 'U', '0', 'U', 'U', 'U', '0', 'U', 'U' ), --| U |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' ), --| X |
 ( '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ), --| 0 |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X' ), --| 1 |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' ), --| Z |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' ), --| W |
 ( '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ), --| L |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', '1', 'X', 'X', '0', '1', 'X' ), --| H |
 ( 'U', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X', 'X', '0', 'X', 'X' )); --| - |
 -----------------------------------------------
 FUNCTION my_and (a, b: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) RETURN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR IS
 ALIAS aa: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO a'LENGTH) IS a;
 ALIAS bb: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO b'LENGTH) IS b;
 VARIABLE result: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 TO a'LENGTH);
 BEGIN
 FOR i IN result'RANGE LOOP
 result(i) := and_table (aa(i), bb(i));
 END LOOP;
 RETURN result;
 END FUNCTION;
 END PACKAGE BODY;
```

Main code:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library functions_and_procedures;
USE functions_and_procedures.PEX9_6.all;
-------------------------------------------------
ENTITY EX9_6 IS
 PORT (x1, x2: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
y: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0));
END ENTITY;
-------------------------------------------------
ARCHITECTURE myand OF EX9_6 IS
BEGIN
 y <= my_and(x1, x2);
END ARCHITECTURE;
-------------------------------------------------
```

```
Error message: ERROR:Xst:2092 - "D:/FPGA/Projects/Pedroni2010/PEX9_6.vhd" line 40: Unsupported type stdlogic_table.
```

Comment: There's nothing googling or searching for your XST 2092 error. I'd suspect XST doesn't support user defined enumeration types as index types of array types. There's nothing apparent in xst.pdf  nor sim.pdf for ISE 14.7. You could note XST User Guide for Virtex-6, Spartan-6, and 7 Series Devices UG687 mentions support for enumeration literals as operands (std_ulogic is a character enumerated type where it's enumation values are character literals). PEX9_6.vhd and (presumably) EX9_6.vhd are valid VHDL, together  they analyze and the latter elaborates and simulates (while not doing much).

Comment: It may not be Spartan-3 versus Spartan-6. There are two different versions of the VHDL parser in XST, each with its own, shall we say, quirks. By default it uses the old one for tha Spartan-3 and the new one for the Spartan-6. Set your project to target the Spartan-3 and look under synthesis options (right click on "Synthesise, and its probably under Advanced, for the "Use new parser" option. Tick it and see if that makes a difference.)

Comment: It shouldn't be a parser issue, rather a semantic issue to do with mapping enumeration values to indexes in lookup tables. Here 'Z' has special meaning in synthesis mapping and '0', '1', 'L', 'H' are mapped to binary values while the remaining Metalogical values are ignored. The issue is reducing the look up table for mapping, missing an inference that the thing should be mapped to a logic function. Mapping the Spartan 6 target using a better set of inferences succeeds. There's no guarantee a Fisher-Price user interface doesn't conflate the distinction. Is the Spartan 6 schematic correct?

Comment: From Chapter 10 "The designs presented in the book were compiled and simulated using *Quartus II Web Edition 8.1* or newer, from Altera, and occasionally *ISE WebPack 10.1* or newer, from Xilinx." You could contemplate ISE wasn't used in this case.